# Pattern match and find another pattern in the next line

Tags: string, bash, shell, append, pattern-matching

find a string1 in a file and check it's next line for string2 if not found append the file with some text after the line of string1.

For example, the following is input file

```
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
string1
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
```

If string2 is not found in the next line of string1, I need to append this file with 10 lines of "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -". The output file should look something like the following.

```
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
string1
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
blah
string1
text string2
blah
blah
```

Help me writing the code in shell without using loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Awk.

```
awk -v s="string1" -v t="string2" '\
$0 ~ s {
    print
    getline
    if($0 !~ t) {
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            for(j=1;j<=32;j++) 
                printf "-"
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
}1' file
```

### Explanation

Set the two string variables for Awk.

```
-v s="string1" -v t="string2"
```

Everything inside the opening bracket is executed if `string1` (variable `s`) is on the line.

`$0` is just Awk's way to expand to the entire line.

```
$0 ~ s {
```

Once the condition is met, we print that line, then go to the next line for processing with `getline`.

Next, if `string2` (variable `t`) is not in the line, we do some loops to print the 10 lines of 32 `-` characters using `printf`.

```
    print
    getline
    if($0 !~ t) {
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            for(j=1;j<=32;j++) 
                printf "-"
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
```

The `1` is just awk shorthand for print.  I use it at the end outside the outermost condition to just print everything else.

```
}1' file
```

The following would do the same thing.

```
}{print}' file
```

Comment: For re-usability's sake, you should add `-v s="string1" -v t="string2"` before your awk call, as in the genral case the value of the string might be stored in an external variable defined earlier in a bash script

Comment: No problem, I think it was actually printing an extra `-` character and line.  I fixed it in the recent edit by initiating the print iterators to `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Yup, see the updated post for a breakdown of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58847/discussion-between-sandeep-and-john-b).

Answer (score 1):

For Finding pattern I can tell you expression, for replacing lines (appending 10 lines) you will have to use sed.
you can get it on google or with some experiments.

I am not providing you all the stuff because that's not expected here.

```
[db2admin@giam20 ~]$  pcregrep -n -v -M 'string1.*\n.*string2' file1.txt | grep string1
8:string1
```

above is regular expression which will give you line no of that line which doesn't contain string2 on next line. now provide this as input to sed to get your job done.

for getting only line no. use cut as,

```
[db2admin@giam20 ~]$  pcregrep -n -v -M 'string1.*\n.*string2' file1.txt | grep string1  |cut -f 1 -d ":"
8
```

Hope this helps.